# How to set up custom ajax pagination in cakephp 2.*

Tags: cakephp-2.0

How do i set up ajax in cakephp without using the default ajax helper? The default ajax helper puts the js code on the page itself, I don't want that. I want it to be set in a seperate js file (ie `general.js`) instead. How do i do that? I have pagination already set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have jquery set up. In your `default.ctp` (`View/Layouts/default.ctp`) add the following line within the `<head>` section:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`

In your `AppController.php` file  (`Controller/AppController.php`) add the following lines

```
function beforeRender() {

        if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
            $this->layout = false;
        }
}
```

This causes the behaviour that when an ajax call is made to an controller action only the view itself is loaded rather than the whole layout.

In your `general.js` file (`webroot/js/general.js`) add the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        ajaxPagingNavigation();
});

function ajaxPagingNavigation() {
    $(".paging a").click(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
              url: $(this).attr('href'),
              cache: false
            }).done(function( html ) {
              $("#content").html(html);
              ajaxPagingNavigation();
            });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```